# Undefined value for request object

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have a problem with NodeJS.

I created a middleware that checks if a JWT inside the cookies exists in the request and tries to validate it.

The problem is, that I'm trying to assign the JWT to a variable and navigating to for example "localhost:80/index", NodeJS returns an error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'jwt' of undefined".

The name of the middleware is "authenticateToken".

This is the route in app.js:

```
app.get('/index', authenticateToken, (req, res) => { res.render('index'); });
```

and im passing this middleware:

```
const jwt               = require('jsonwebtoken');

function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {

    var token = req.cookies.jwt;

    if (token) {
        
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, function(err, decodedToken) {

            if (err) {

                console.log(err.message);
                res.redirect('/login');

            }
            else {

                console.log(decodedToken);

                next();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }

    
}

module.exports = { authenticateToken };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The solution was to add "app.use(cookieParser());" in app.js.

Answer (score 1):

The error is indicating that `req` object doesn't have a `cookies` field, so when you're attempting to get the 'jwt' field of the cookies object, it is a null-reference exception.

You can use the [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) features in Node to avoid this NRE.

Assuming that when things are working the `cookies` field will exist on `req` and that it is an object with a `jwt` field, then you can do:

`var token = req.cookies?.jwt ?? undefined;`

Comment: The cookie does exist. When I do "console.log(req.headers.cookie)" it outputs the cookie, but when i do "console.log(req.cookies)" it says undefined.

Comment: `req.headers.cookie` is different than `req.cookies`.  Does `req.headers.cookie` contain your jwt object?